# How to choose nth row in JQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

eg choose the fifth row in suggestions?

How to?

such as: enter `s`,the suggestions are:

- ActionScript
- AppleScript
- Asp
- BASIC
- ColdFusion
- Haskell
- JavaScript
- Lisp
- Scala
- Scheme

how to choose the `ColdFusion` without mousedown or click?

my test code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        open:function(event,ui){
            $('.ui-menu-item:eq(5) a').click();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

it doesn't work..

ths!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [event-open](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-open) to trigger a virtual click on the nth row

exemple

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    open: function(event, ui) {

        $("#tags").autocomplete().data("autocomplete").menu._trigger("selected", event, {
            item: $('.ui-menu-item:eq(5)')
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to limit yourself the result set, i.e. by using the [search](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#event-search) event

To select an item without mousedown or click, you can use the arrow keys of your keyboard !